# Create Dynamic Tree Structure using java

Tags: java

I need to implement dynamic tree structure in my application. and fill all that node in my map. so that i can carry that map to client side and display it on my jsp. I will read the data from my xml and fill it into my map but i am not getting proper way to fill the map. can anyone suggest me the best optimize way.

Answer (score 0):

Per default I would use the native [DOM API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing) for that. It feels a bit clunky but does what it needs to do.